# How to ignore specific errors from the New Relic Dashboard

Tags: node.js, newrelic

Helllo,

My application is a web server that fires many requests to other servers. We set up a maximum timeout on those requests, and whenever the timeout is reached, the connection is closed and a ESOCKETTIMEDOUT rises.

```
Error: socket hang up
at createHangUpError (http.js:1472:15)
at Socket.socketCloseListener (http.js:1522:23)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at TCP.close (net.js:465:12)
```

I want to exclude these errors from the New Relic Dashboard, since they distort the error rate and other metrics. Hiding them doesn't work either, because they still count in the error rate.

How can remove specific errors (that do not have a HTTP status code) from my Dashboard?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass status codes to ignore to the error collector. If you are configuring the New Relic agent using environment variables you can use a comma separated list of codes as the value for `NEW_RELIC_ERROR_COLLECTOR_IGNORE_ERROR_CODES`.

See [the README](https://github.com/newrelic/node-newrelic/blob/d5541da185332273d8a2b9bc1417a3d88a9ea745/README.md#configuring-the-module).

If you are using `newrelic.js` to do so you can set the `error_collector.ignore_codes` value to an Array of status codes to ignore:

See the [example config](https://github.com/newrelic/node-newrelic/blob/d5541da185332273d8a2b9bc1417a3d88a9ea745/lib/config.default.js#L185).

**Important caveat**: when setting this value manually you are overriding the default value of `404` which means that if you do not specify `404`  in your manual configuration the Error Collector will start logging all `404` errors in your application (which you probably do not want).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have javascript, I'm not sure if my solution can help you but I'll answer in the hope it does.

I use Java agent, and we have the same kind of problem. So far the only way that I found that can do something near what I want is having the specific errors wrapped in a dedicated exception ("NewRelicIgnorableException") and wrap whatever error I don't want to see in it.

Then I'd have to go into the dashboard/application and select "error collection". Last, I'd fill in the "Ignore these errors" with the full package name AND exception class name, like com.mypackage.NewRelicIgnorableException. Save and enjoy. These particular errors should not impact your apdex, but they will still count towards RPM and other metrics.

Other solutions have drawbacks. For example if I call ignoreexception the RPM and time metrics will not count. If you click the "hide error" button you only hide them from the error panel, but everything else will be as usual. If you ignore by status code you can get more or less the same results as ignoring the specific exception, but without any hope for fine control.

It's a pity that there's so little documentation on their site, I had to run tests to find these out.